# Bootable USB with Ubuntu 20.04 and biggest storage size under root "/"

Tags: partitioning, usb, gparted, usb-drive

I have a bootable usb with ubuntu 20.04 on it.

I want to first "try ubuntu" and then download some 5gb of files which probably will go into "/". Is this correct?

However "/" seems to be small. So how to increase that to have a bigger size storage on my usb?

See image... (would be great if somehow I could add 10gb to my bootable ubuntu usb for storage of "try ubuntu" only)

Gparted shows me nothing I can work with.

[image]

Comment: This is a false problem in any angle you look at it. If you want to use a live session for that is fine and you can save what you want to any other external media as long as it's properly mounted. And for general usage you can either have a live session with persistence or a proper full installation in a USB drive. A typical live session's purpose is to TEST and eventually INSTALL the OS, nothing else.

Comment: How big is your Bootable USB? How did you make it, Rufus or Etcher? Is it a persistent install? The / partition may be read/write FAT32 or NTFS as made by Rufus or Universal, or it may be read only ISO9660 filesystem as made by Etcher or dd. If ISO9660 you can create a NTFS partition on it for saving data from a windows or Linux computer

Comment: I suspect that `/` is not really the first partition you see. Also note your first partition is ISO9660 (a.k.a. CDFS), not writable. - 1. Can you briefly explain why you want to put the file in `/`? - 2. Can you also put your output of `df -hT` and `mount` when running in your live session? Since your USB has extra free space, if putting files in `/` is not mandatory, the obvious solution is to create an additional partition there and mount it for storage (note that this may cause confusion when using OS like Windows since it does not recognize USB flash drives with >1 readable partitions).

Answer (score 0):

When starting the live USB the system only sees the first two partitions, not the free one. It's read only system - everything you download will reside in your memory, but not physically on the USB stick.
What you could do: take another USB stick (empty) and install you system from the first USB to the second one.
Then you work with your second USB- make sure that your UEFI/Bios boots it first.